# Google indexed pages for one page site

Tags: pages, template-redirect, google-search

I have created a one page site with wordpress. The basic idea used was to combine pages and their templates into index.php.

The problem is that when crawlers work on the site, they get the links for the pages which is good, but they display the page as single item and not part of the one page site.

How can I redirect these pages into the main site? Is there a plugin or a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not wordpress related question but I will answer it without any special reason.

First of all... all pages from old website are indexed on google and those indexed pages can not be deindexed at the same moment when you change the website. That is the reason why all pages show on google... so you have to wait or you have to play around in Google webmaster tools in order to speed up that process.

You can create redirections simply with this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-redirect/

I hope that this will help you to understand what is going on.

But... as experienced SEM guru I would never combine all those pages into one page because of many reasons.... but that is not important now.

Comment: I understand the risks and the SEM you talk about. After all it is more of a "brochure" type site rather than actual information site, so it has the minimal content it can have for such thing. I agree, I am not a sem/sef/seo expert myself also to know about these stuff, unless being pointed to something to explain the whys and the dont's.

Comment: In that case just add those redirections. That will be fine.